# Systemd-networkd does not seem to find interface in the container

Tags: virtual-machine, systemd-networkd

I am trying to set up an nspawn-container on Ubuntu 20.04.3. The host network-configuration contains a bridge interface:

```
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet *  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 * prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 41:8a:5b:d8:83:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5914822  bytes 888728796 (888.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 449  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30323548  bytes 37836188291 (37.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The container is started with:

```
systemd-nspawn -UbM helloworld --network-bridge=br0
```

When the container is started, the `vb-helloworld` interface is created:

```
vb-helloworld: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::c8fc:b8ff:fed1:176  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ca:fc:b8:d1:01:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

In the container, there is an interface `host0`, which should be handled by `systemd-networkd`, config `/etc/systemd/network/host0.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=host0
[Network]
DHCP=false
Address=*:*:*:*::100/64
Gateway=fe80::1
DNS=2a01:4ff:*::*:1
Address=192.168.50.10/24
Gateway=192.168.50.1
DNS=192.168.50.2
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes
[Link]
MACAddress=f6:d9:2b:ba:7a:1d
ARP=true
RequiredForOnline=yes
[Address]
Address=*:*:*:*::100/64
Scope=global
[Route]
Gateway=fe80::1
Scope=global
```

The container has the interface:

```
host0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.214.0  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 fe80::f4d9:2bff:feba:7a1d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether f6:d9:2b:ba:7a:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
...
```

Unfortunately, networkd does not seem to find the interface `host0`. Addresses are not assigned, neither ip4 nor ip6. When I change the `Name` parameter in the section `[Match]` to `*`, the addresses are assigned to the `lo` interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Systemd already comes with a networkd config matching the `host0` interface:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/network/80-container-host0.network
```

Networkd reads all .network files in asciibetical order, and the first matching file wins. (In ASCII, the order is roughly `0-9 A-Z a-z`.) For your custom configuration to take priority, its file name must be ordered *before* `80-container-host0`, such as `50-custom-host0`.

(The directory only matters if two files have the same name – in that case, a file in /etc has priority over an identically named file in /usr/lib.)